# Matrix/Vector initialization performance

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

This is more of an educational question, there is no specific problem I am trying to solve. I would like some insight into what happens "behind the scenes" in the following scenario:

We have 2 `int`s, `w` and `h`, and we need a matrix (`vector<vector<int>>`) of `0`s. There are multiple ways to do this and I would like to know which one performs best (probably this means which one performs the least copies).

Option 1:

```
vector<vector<int>> m;

for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
{
    m.push_back(vector<int>());
    for (j = 0; j < w; j++)
        m[i].push_back(0);
}
```

Option 2:

```
vector<vector<int>> m;

for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
    m.push_back(vector<int>(w, 0));
```

Option 3:

```
vector<vector<int>> m(h, vector<int>(w, 0));
```

Is the temporary value at `m.push_back(vector<int>());` / `m.push_back(vector<int>(w, 0));` created in memory and then also copied into `m`? If it is wouldn't it be better to use option 1 to minimize copying? (suppose we are only talking about larger arrays, say 1,000,000 x 1,000,000). Same dilemmas for option 3; which tends to be faster (at least on paper) and why would it be?

Comment: Depending on the values of `h` and `w`, there might be many reallocations of the memory handled by the vectors in options 1 and 2. In option 3 there's no reallocations. And for the first and second option the `push_back` will leads to the temporary vector to be *moved* and not copied (but there will still be reallocations). As a way to improve options 1 and 2, use [`emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) instead. But the "best" way (of the three shown) is option 3.

Comment: You mention "copies", but which example do you think has a copy? And why do you think that's bad?

Answer (score 1):

If you want performance for a Matrix class, you don't use `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` in the first place. You write a proper class that encapsulates a one-dimensional `std::vector<T>`. A vector of vectors is fragmented in memory.

A one-trillion element matrix is technically possible on commercial hardware nowadays, but to initialize it you really, really want multiple threads. That's another practical objection against your 3 examples.

Having said that, for small experiments all your code is fine.

Comment: As it was stated in the question, the example given is just a simple example to illustrate the general problem of STL containers having to contain lots of other containers and that I would like insight into what happens behind the scenes.

Comment: @RaresDima: My answer is just a simple example why the "general"  problem isn't actually general in practice.  These concerns need to be addressed on a case-by-case basis, generally when profiling shows an actual problem. C++ has decent performance out of the box, especially since C++11 added move operations.