# C++ programming , build a matrix using std::vector

Tags: c++

how I can build a matrix in c++ using std::vector with default element?

I tried:

```
vector<vector<int> > matrix;
for(int i = 0; i<row; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j<column; j++)
    {
         matrix[i][j] = 0 ;  //here
    }
}
```

> I need the matrix to be initialized automatically to default number (0) if I don't give the  matrix element
> and to be  initialized with a number (for example 5) if I give it when I ask to build a matrix

Comment: use vector<vector<int> > mat(row, vector<int> (column, number))

Comment: and if I don't give the number it understand that I want it to be default (0)??

Comment: Your try successfully created a 0x0 matrix, in the same way that `vector<int> vec;` creates a 0-element vector. Do you know how to create a vector with `n` elements (for some number `n`)? *(Build up to your goal. Master the small pieces, and you'll be well on your way to mastering the whole.)*

Comment: do you mean  vector<int>  v1(8,8)??

Comment: @Y.D Using the same number for both arguments is often a bad idea (leads to confusion). Let's say `vector<int> v1(6,8)`, which creates a vector of `6` elements, each of which has the value `8`. You want a vector of `row` elements, each of which is a vector. You can worry about what those inner vectors are for the next step.

Comment: Potentially informative: [Matrix/Vector initialization performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62990325/matrix-vector-initialization-performance)

Answer (score 0):

Let's create a `5 x 5` matrix of `0's`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int row = 5, col = 5;
    vector<vector<int>> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {  
        vector<int> tempV; 
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) { 
            tempV.push_back(0); 
        } 
        v.push_back(tempV); 
    }
    
    //print the matrix 
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) { 
        for (int j = 0; j < v[i].size(); j++) 
            cout << v[i][j] << " "; 
        cout << endl; 
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: `vector<vector<int>> matrix(ROW, vector<int>(COL,0);` will do all of the necessary set-up. Refrain from using macros to represent constants. `constexpr int ROW = 5;` will give the same results while providing type safety and no chance of accidental preprocessor substitutions.